Set a list as a argument for SQL query in Kotlin
I have this list
("item 1" , "item 2")

This query
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE SYSTEM in (?)

The way I send and argument to ? is like this
pstmt.setString(1,list)

I have tried different ways to format the values inside the list to be in this format for the SQL query
('item1' , 'item')

But it never works because when I send over the argument I belive the whole string just gets put inside a " ", which makes the comma, be inside the " " which is a problem.
Is there any way for me to use a list as an argument for a SQL query? thank you

Does this answer your question? PreparedStatement with list of parameters in a IN clause

@perpetter Maybe you could change "in" to "IN" as it is a keyword? All the other keywords are in uppercase.
